# Renaming SAMAccountName in Active Directory and update in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

We would be updating the SAMAccountName in Active Directory and should update the profiles in SharePoint 2010.

***Eg:***

```
Old SAMAccountName : ABC
New SAMAccountName : XYZ
```

I hope that we may just need to run the below script once the SAMAccountName is updated on Active Directory.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|demo\ABC" -Web https://test.demo.com
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "i:0#.w|demo\XYZ" -IgnoreSID
```

Please let me know if we misses any thing? and does it impact user's permissions?

Comment: Point to consider - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/02/24/interesting-side-effects-of-the-move-spuser-powershell-cmdlet.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't see any issue, but if you miss a user then that user will get access denied. i would also recommend a Full User Profile Sync after the Change.